# JavaScript Buttons Conflict With Each Other

Tags: javascript, css, button, input, background

Hi i have 3 different buttons on my page that are used to change the background image/colour of the page.
The problem i have is that my main toggle button doesn't toggle the background once the image has been set to it using 1 of the other buttons.

If i press the button that runs this function...

```
$( "body" ).toggleClass( "bgimg", 1000 );
```

then i can set the background image using this button.

```
$("#SetBG").click(function() {
```

If i don't press the toggleClass button then the background image does not set.
Its like the .bgimg class has to be set on the page before i can edit it?

Another problem is that once i have set the background image the .toggleClass button doesnt work! the class .bgimg does not toggle.

CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
}

.bgimg {
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="ImageURL"></input>
<button id="SetBG">Set Background</button>
<button id="ReSetBG">Re-Set</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#DialogBackground" ).dialog({
    open: function (event, ui) {$(".ui-widget-overlay").css({opacity: 0, filter: "Alpha(Opacity=00)"});},
    modal:true,
    autoOpen:false,
    height:450,
    width:450,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [{
        id:"remove",
        text: "Remove/Add Background",
        click: function() {
        $( "body" ).toggleClass( "bgimg", 1000 );
        return false;
        }
    }]
    });

$("#SetBG").click(function() {
    var URL = document.getElementById("ImageURL").value;
    $(".bgimg").css('background-image',"url(" +URL +")");
    return false;
});

$('#ReSetBG').click(function() {
$('.bgimg').css('background-image', "url('http://192.168.0.4/DesktopVersion/Inc/Images/Background/DarkWood.jpg')");
return false;
});
```

If someone could please show me what code is wrong or conflicting that would be great.

Comment: I think that the code is incomplete to understand your conflict. Could you create on jsfiddle a page like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MrRDq/ with a complete code?

Comment: yea i tried to but for some reason the JQuery dialogs are not working. I did include the JQuery UI but still no luck. Also i don't think there is any code missing form what i gave you? the HTML goes with the JavaScript the only thing i left out was the button to open the dialog :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i don't press the toggleClass button then the background image does not set. Its like the .bgimg class has to be set on the page before i can edit it?
>
> Another problem is that once i have set the background image the .toggleClass button doesnt work! the class .bgimg does not toggle.

You are mixing up 2 different css concepts, inline rules and stylesheet rules. What you are doing when you say something similar to :

```
$('.bgimg').css('background-image', "url('http://192.168.0.4/DesktopVersion/Inc/Images/Background/DarkWood.jpg')");
```

Is target the element with class name `bgimg` and apply this inline css rule:

```
background-image: url('http://192.168.0.4/DesktopVersion/Inc/Images/Background/DarkWood.jpg')"
```

So if there isn't an element with the class `bgimg` nothing will happen. However if it does exist an **inline** css rule will be applied. If you remove the class nothing will change because the css isn't defined in a stylesheet by class but on the element itself. For your stuff to work the way you want it to you will want to either define 2 different styles in your css and use `toggleClass` to switch between the two or leave the class `bgimg` on the element always and use `$('.bgimg').css('background-image', "")` to remove the background image and the existing code to add/change.

Comment: Thank you very much! i decided to always have the `.bgimg` on the element in the end :)